# Can't install ec2-consistent snapshot - Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.10.1)

Tags: perl, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to install ec2-consistent snapshot on AWS AMI release 2014.03 and according to [this page](http://www.thatsgeeky.com/2011/05/ec2-consistent-snapshot-on-amazons-linux-ami/) I need to first:

`yum --enablerepo=epel install perl-Net-Amazon-EC2 perl-File-Slurp perl-DBI perl-DBD-MySQL perl-Net-SSLeay perl-IO-Socket-SSL perl-Time-HiRes perl-Params-Validate ca-certificates`

which fails with

```
Error: Package: perl-Class-MOP-1.12-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.10.1)
Error: Package: perl-Net-Amazon-EC2-0.14-2.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.10.1)
Error: Package: perl-Moose-1.15-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.10.1)
```

Perl version installed is `v5.16.3`, so I reckon it should be backward compatible with 5.10? How do I fix this problem?

Comment: What version of `epel` repo are you sing. There are two, version 5 and version 6. These mostly go hand-in-hand with CentOS 5 and CentOS 6 respectively. As Amazon Linux is a spin off from CentOS, you may want to check the version of epel that you are using. Check `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` for confirming the epel version/

Comment: @slayedbylucifer, I'm using el 6 (sorry your comment did not show up in top bar for some reason)

Comment: I have the same issue on smaller scale—trying to install monitorix deps: `yum install httpd rrdtool rrdtool-perl perl-libwww-perl perl-MailTools perl-MIME-Lite perl-CGI perl-DBI perl-XML-Simple perl-Config-General perl-HTTP-Server-Simple` gets me
`Error: Package: perl-HTTP-Server-Simple-0.42-1.el6.noarch (epel)
          Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.10.1)`. I've got both EPEL and RPM Fusion enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably related to a patching issue on Amazon's AMIs as explained here https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=534491

There is a workaround but it requires you to revert back to an earlier image and lock it down for now which is not ideal.